# jasmine expectedAsync for async function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running the following test:

```
it("should get rejected", async done => {
      class someTest {
        async run(){
          return this.rejectFunc();
        }
        async rejectFunc(){
          return new Promise( (_,reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
              reject()
            },300)
          })
        }
      }

      const test = new someTest();
      spyOn(test, 'rejectFunc').and.callThrough();
      test.run()      
      await expectAsync(test.rejectFunc).toBeRejected();  
      done();
    });
```

But the test fails on timeout:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
> specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

What am I doing wrong? I want to run the `run` method and verify that `rejectFunc` gets rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first time I am seeing `expectAsync` but it expects to take a promise and not the name of a function.

So try this:

```
// call the function with ()
await expectAsync(test.rejectFunc()).toBeRejected();
```

Another way to test for you would be:

```
try {
  await test.rejectFunc();
} catch (error) {
  // call done here, meaning promise was rejected and therefore we can assert
  // it was rejected
  done();
}
```

Edit

```
const test = new someTest();
spyOn(test, 'rejectFunc').and.callThrough();
try {
  await test.run();
} catch (e) {
  expect(test.rejectFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
    
done();
```

Comment: But I don't want to call `test.rejectFunc` directly - just to verify that it is called and rejected when I run `test.run()`

Comment: Check out my edit, you can try to do that as well.